# Normalized icon for BOYLAT

Tags: qgis, svg, icon

I try to find normalized icons to use for the BOYLAT ( lateral buoy )

I find description, but for the boylat it seems that different shape to show different buoy
link for the description

http://www.caris.com/s-57/object/boylat.htm

and the link for the list of shape

http://www.caris.com/s-57/attribut/boyshp.htm

Comment: This page may help you further: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenSeaMap/Buoys#Lateral_Buoys

Comment: Agree with the OpenSeaMap suggestion. If you go to [their website](http://www.openseamap.org/), you should see some lateral buoys and how they styled them.

Comment: their website is very interresting but i need to download icons for my application, if you have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to download svg file for icons it is free and in svg format

http://all-free-download.com/free-vector/download/international_sphere_buoy_maritime_symbol_clip_art_11235.html